# Flask Render template is not displaying the message parsed to html page?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, flask, render

**Problem:**

Iam having a flask based search bar on search iam fetching the data from the MySQL and want to display on the same page.

**Code:**

```
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
                conn = MySQLdb.connect(user="analyst", passwd="abc123", db="somedb", host="127.0.0.1")
                cursor =conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute("SELECT * from some where domain = '%s'"%(request.form['search']))
                logger.info('Query is {}'.format("SELECT * from samples where md5 = '%s'"%(request.form['search'])))
                data = cursor.fetchall()
                logger.info('Data fetched is {}'.format(str(data)))
                return render_template("search.htm", records=cursor.fetchall(), title='User',)
    except Exception as e:
        return render_template("search.htm", records=str(e), title='User',)
    return render_template('search.htm',
                           title='Cuckoo User Page',
                           )
```

**templates/search.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>{{ title }}</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }} - Search Page</h1>
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" value="{{ request.form.search }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
    {{ records }}
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Issue Observed:**
Whenever i search something it is successfully fetched from db and iam storing it in logs.But when parsing the same to html page it is displaying as ()

**Logs:**

```
2017-09-08 11:28:14,098 - app.views - INFO - Query is SELECT * from some where domain = 'akizekij.bovseter.org '
2017-09-08 11:28:14,098 - app.views - INFO - Data fetched is (('a', '134', '11333', 'akizekij.bovseter.org', '10.10', '13', datetime.date(2017, 2, 28), datetime.date(2017, 2, 28), '', 0L, 1L),)
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling `fetchall()` 2 times which will return you empty tuple (or dict) for second. on the ther hand logging the first fetch - and it show  normally.

quick fix should be like below.

```
data = cursor.fetchall()
logger.info('Data fetched is {}'.format(str(data)))
return render_template("search.htm", records=data, title='User',)
                                            ^^^^^^
```

**edit**

```
>>> import pymysql as mysql
>>> conn = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='123456', database='demoapp')
<pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7f31e5973110>
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT name FROM categories")
21
>>> d = cur.fetchall()
>>> d
(('Relationships',), ('Business',), ('Celebrity',), ('Events',), ('Fashion',), ('Law',), ('Fitness',), ('Medical',), ('MOVIES',), ('MUSIC',), ('Social',), ('Sport',), ('Tech',), ('Travel',), ('VIDEO',), ('Strains',), ('Food',), ('Education',), ('Activism',), ('Pets',), ('Headlines',))
>>> f = cur.fetchall()
>>> f
()
```

ref: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/cursors.py

Lines 295, 74, 43